# Why is this reading like this?

Tags: kanji, readings, manga, katakana, furigana

[image]

Why is this reading like this? Looking this up I had to search the radicals individually on Jisho. The furigana reading... is it just flat out wrong? Furthermore, why is the word structured like this? There is katakana right after a hiragana character.

The context is that they are ninjas who are running away from someone more formidable than them.

Can someone please clear this up or identify if it's wrong.

Comment: You said you checked Jisho, but did you see this entry? https://jisho.org/word/%E9%80%80%E3%81%8F-2

Comment: "The furigana reading... is it just flat out wrong?" - what do you think it should be instead, and why? "There is katakana right after a hiragana character." - why should this be a problem?

Comment: I can't remember if I saw that entry but it's not entirely obvious that the textbubble is that entry for a beginner and I was unsure. 

@Karl. What do you mean what do I think it should be? I asked a QUESTION, because I do not know. It's just that it was different to what my IME was giving me as well as what was on Jisho when I checked. As for hiragana and katakana; I have never seen a singular word that has a mix of both hiragana and katakana, that was the problem. Not sure why you're being this condescending. Some people get confused by things and that's why this site exists. :|

Comment: "What do you mean what do I think it should be?" Exactly as I say: in my view, *it doesn't make sense to say "why is it this way?"* if you don't already have in mind a different way that it could or should be instead. From that perspective, the pronunciation could be anything. I legitimately don't understand how you perceive any condescension; it certainly was not intended. Similarly: if you're "unsure" of something but you did try to do your own research, it's better to say up front what you saw in your research and what you concluded and why, so we can properly understand the question.

Comment: Okay. My apologies. I will be clearer in my contextualisation next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word that is used in this panel is [退く](https://jisho.org/word/%E9%80%80%E3%81%8F-2) in the imperative form.

In this case, the imperative form is made by changing 退く into 退け by taking the last う (the one in く) and changing it into a え, which then changes く to け

The ツ, more or less, is just for dramatic effect. It's kind of like someone saying "Retree...!!!" instead of just "Retreat!!!" in this case

Comment: "For dramatic effect", yes; but it indicates cutting the end of the word short rather than elongating the main vowel.

Comment: I definitely could see that being the case given the panel. Updated answer to reflect this